# Outlook VSTO - How to intercept an email at the time of its closure

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am writing some code to intercept a user and prompt them to do something when certain conditions are not met.  My issue is that I am expecting the user to close the email by clicking the x in the top right hand corner.  I am listening for this by using the

Outlook.ItemEvents_10_CloseEventHandler

basic code:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        public Outlook.MailItem OriginalMailItem
        ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)OriginalMailItem).Close += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_CloseEventHandler(Item_Close);
    }
```

the function:

```
void Item_Close(ref bool Cancel)
    {
    // Do something with the OriginalMailItem here
        private Outlook.MAPIFolder workersavefolder = ohaworker.Inbox.Folders[ohaworker.WorkerJobFolderName];
        Outlook.MailItem workerMailItem = OriginalMailItem.Move(workersavefolder);
    }
```

I am unable to do anything here with the target email given the following error:

'The item's properties and methods cannot be used inside this event procedure.'

I think the basic reason is probably because the email is about to close.  My questions is - is there any other way I can still grab this email after closure and do something with it?

My initial though was that I might grab the EntryID or Conversation ID and then somehow grab the email via another means, but I cant seem to find anything to connect to so that I can continue the code.  Comments and feedback welcomed!

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can reopen the item by its entry id later when you are out of the event handler. You can use either a `Timer` (use the one from the Forms namespace as it runs on the main thread) or use `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync()`

Comment: Thankyou for your response.  Is there any benefit to using one option over the other?  Timer feels like an easier approach, but I'd prefer to take the most elegant / efficient approach. I've caught myself out in the past taking what was probably the easy / shortcut option; only to have to revisit my code and redo.   Part of learing I guess.

Comment: They both do the same thing - execute your code after you are out of the event handler and no longer a subject to limitations on some methods/properties.

Comment: Timer was a very easy option.  I have not yet tried the Dispatcher option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method which returns a Microsoft Outlook item identified by the specified entry ID (if valid). So, to get a valid object and get its properties you can use the `GetItemFromID` method.

Be aware, the Outlook object model uses a single threaded apartment model, so any access from a secondary thread may lead to an exception generated by the OOM. You need to use the main thread if you want to deal with OOM. That's why you need to get any event which is fired on the main thread - [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=net-5.0) or any other mechanism.